# NullPointerException in a JTextField.getText() inside a actionPerformed event

Tags: java, jtextfield, actionlistener

I'm having a **NullPointerException** in a *JTextField.getText()* inside a *actionPerformed* event:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class myForm extends JInternalFrame
{
    private JTextField txtName;
    private String name;

    public myForm()
    {
        super("My Form", true, true, true, true);

        txtName = new JTextField();

        JButton button = new JButton("button");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                name = txtName.getText(); // here is the NullPointerException 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ContatoFormulario$1.actionPerformed(ContatoFormulario.java:80)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6216)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5981)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4583)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4413)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4220)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4150)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4413)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Anyone has a idea? I already try to search over the web and don't find any solution.

This problem occurs with more frequency when we re-instanciate the JTextField like this:

```
public class myForm extends JInternalFrame
{
    private JTextField txtName;

    public myForm()
    {
        JTextField txtName = new JTextField();        
    }
 }
```

But this is not the case, any idea?

Comment: Your first example is uncompilable, as you have an invalid syntax for the addActionListener() method, and you never actually add the button to the frame, so it should never fire an ActionEvent.  We'll need to see the actual code to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first piece of code shouldn't. Have you removed something, or got confused what you have compiled?

The second piece of code has the local variable hiding the field.

Comment: Yes, I found it, the error is not on txtName.getText(). Yes I ommited some code, but just to simplify the post.

The original line of code is:

contact.setName(txtName.getText());

I forgot to instanciate the 'contact' object.

Thank you guys.

Comment: It's best to do a little debugging first before posting a question, so you'll post the actual problem and not a red herring.